# quickSort - StackOverflowException

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to write a quicksort algorithm. Please look at the following code:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] tab, int lowIndex, int highIndex) {
    if (tab.length == 0 || tab == null) {
        return;
    }

    int i = lowIndex;
    int j = highIndex;

    int pivot = tab[tab.length / 2];

    while (i <= j) {
        while (tab[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (tab[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }

        if (i <= j) {
            int c = tab[i];
            tab[i] = tab[j];
            tab[j] = c;
            i++;
            j--;
        }

        if (lowIndex < j) {
            quickSort(tab, lowIndex, j); // error !!!
        }
        if (i < highIndex) {
            quickSort(tab, i, highIndex);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError. What is wrong ?

Comment: A StackOverflowError occurs when you call too many methods without returning.  However, asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: At the first "if" statement, `tab == null` check should be the first, I think.

Comment: Check your `pivot` element as dasblinkenlight says. Maybe line `if (i <= j) {` should be `if (i < j) {` because swapping to equal element doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
int pivot = tab[tab.length / 2];
```

You have to find the pivot in the provided slice, not globally in the `tab`.

```
int pivot = tab[lowIndex + (highIndex - lowIndex)/ 2];
```

Also your condition to terminate the recursion is wrong. The length of the table doesn't change. You have to check if `lowIndex >= highIndex`